# How to connect batteries of different capacity in parallel

Tags: batteries, current, 18650

I have a power bank that takes 8 18650 li-ion cells in parallel.

I have 6 cells that i salvaged from an old laptop battery that each have @ 2400mAh remaining. Looking at the specs the max charge current is 2600mA and max discharge current is 5200mA with a cut-off voltage of 2.75V. The cell code is ICR18650-26F for more info.

I also have 6 cells from a power drill battery that each have @1900 mAh remaining.
The max discharge current is 22A with a cut-off voltage of 2.5V. Cell code is NR18650-20R.

The max input and output of the powerbank is 5V 2A.

I want maximun capacity in my power bank so i was thinking of using 6 2400mA cells and 2 1900mA cells but i'm not sure how this configuration will work given the different capacities and specs of the cells.

Also when discharging, will the bigger cells continue to charge the smaller cells until they all balance out and then continue to discharge at an equal rate? (I'm thinking at the principle of communicating vessels).
However, if they all discharge at different rates what will happen to the small cells once they are depleted compared to bigger cells.